# How to get file opened from dialog in another function?

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a function `open_data` that opens a file dialog for me to select a specific file. I want to access the selected file in another function `run_data` within the same file. Below is a sample demonstration of my code. Any suggestions to the selected file in the `run_data` function are welcomed.

```
def open_data():
    dialog = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir=".\", title="Select A Data",
                                        filetypes=(("numpy files", "*.npy"),
                                        ("all files", "*.*")))

    for data in dialog:
         print(data, end="")

def run_data():
    ## I want to access the selected data from the above dialog in this function##
    return data
```

Comment: Why not just `return dialog` at the end of `open_data`?

Comment: I want to make computation on the data in the ```run_data``` function

Comment: `".\"` should be `".\\"`

Comment: Put the selected files in a global variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`askopenfilename()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dialog.html#tkinter.filedialog.askopenfilename) returns a **file name** not an open file, so you will need to open it in order to be able to access its contents. You also need to check because the value returned can be `None` if the user canceled the dialog without selecting anything.

Since you want to retrieve the data in a separate function, you will need to use a `global` variable to hold the data between function calls.

```
data = None  # Initialize global variable.

def open_data():
    global data

    filename = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir=".\", title="Select A Data",
                                          filetypes=(("numpy files", "*.npy"),
                                          ("all files", "*.*")))
    if not filename:
        data = None  # User didn't select a file.
    else:
        data = np.load(filename)

def run_data():
    return data
```

Comment: ```np.load(filename)``` raises ```FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C'```

Comment: Print out `filename` and see what is being passed to `np.load()` — is it valid?

Comment: Yes, its valid. It prints out the path of the selected data ```C:/Users/Desktop/data/data126.npy```. However, I'm not sure why ```np.load()``` gives that error. I have even tried to put data in ```" "``` as in ```np.load("data")``` but still not working, got this error ```PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'data'```

Comment: That's strange (because it looks right). Are you sure the file isn't corrupt? You can check that by loading it by directly specifying it's name. If that works, then I don't know what the problem is.

Comment: I am able to load the data now however when I print(data) after the ```open_data``` function, I get ```None```. I guess I will have to call ```open_data``` in the ```run_data``` function before the ```return data```

Comment: `open_data()` needs to be called before `run_data()` so it can ask the user for a filename and then set global `data` variable to the contents of the file selected — otherwise `data` will be `None`. If data doesn't change after calling `open_data()` the user didn't make a selection.